# Can you assign a name to a Web Worker?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, web-worker

If you start two web workers that use the same JavaScript file, there is no way in Firefox to distinguish them in `about:debugging#workers`. You get two identical entries (listed under "Other Workers").

For debugging, it would be convenient to assign names to web workers. For instance, in Java there is [Thread#setName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setName(java.lang.String)). Is there something equivalent in JavaScript's web worker API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary, I would recommend to combine both approaches provided by the8472 and Patrick Evans to get the best debugging experience:

1. Setting the name via [the web worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker) (for details, see [the8472's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44886407/783510))
2. Adding a dummy parameter to the URL, so it will show up in Firefox (for details, see [Patrick Evans' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44886498/783510))

For example, instead of

```
let worker = new Worker(url);
```

write something like this

```
let worker = new Worker(`${url}?name=SomeContext`, { name: 'Some useful context' });
```

At least in Firefox 54, the optional name parameter is not shown in the worker overview. Therefore, extending the URL is still useful. On the other hand, using the API (even though it is not currently used by Firefox from what I see) seems like a good idea when you look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker):

> name: A DOMString specifying an identifying name for the DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope representing the scope of the worker, which is mainly useful for debugging purposes.

I wish browsers would show the name in the worker overview (e.g., `about:debugging#workers` in Firefox), which would render the URL extension workaround obsolete.

Note that by modifying the URL the browser may end up doing extra work and may even fetch extra data over the network. Depending on your use case, this could be a disadvantage if you intend to use the workaround in production. In my specific case, the overview is not an issue as the code is statically served (it is part of a browser extension).

Answer (score 9):

The [Worker() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker) takes an optional options argument which can contain a name property, for example:

```
let workerOne = new Worker(URL, {
  'name' : 'nameOfWorkerOne'
}),
    workerTwo = new Worker(URL, {
  'name' : 'nameOfWorkerTwo'
});
```

> Nice, I overlooked that. Do you know if it is portable?

There is a [link to the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/#dom-worker) on the MDN page I linked above. If you follow the white rabbit you will see that the options argument is part of the spec.

It can be read as [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope/name) property of the global object in the worker, e.g. in a debugger.

Comment: I brought a simple code example into the answer to show how this options Object might be used to define the name for the web workers; I'm sorry if you didn't want this, obviously a roll-back won't be contested :)